Disable activity within pipeline in Azure Synapse/Data Factory

We are building a Data Warehouse on Synapse using ETL. We need a way to stop and start activities automatically in case of issues or during deployments, as the current manual disable/enable option is impractical for production.
Is there an alternative method to automate this?
Would a PowerShell command be available to enable/disable activities?
We also considered using an If condition with a control table to check each activity, but this seems too complex.

The Enable/Disable is not dynamic, so some kind of metadata driven control lookup is probably your only realistic solution.


Is there an alternative method to automate this? Would a PowerShell command be available to enable/disable activities?

Agreed with @Joel Cochran and AFAIK, there is no other Dynamic or automated way like PowerShell command to enable/disable activities within the Azure data factory Pipeline. You need to do it manually only from the Azure Data Factory Portal.
So, the possible solution is with the help of metadata driven table which help to decide if the particular activity should be enabled or disabled with help of lookup activity and If Activity of azure data factory

Create a table on SQL where you specified which activity need to be enabled or which need to be disabled. as below:




ActivityName
IsEnabled




Activity1
1


Activity2
0




Use lookup activity to check the IsEnabled value from the above table with below query and pass it to If activity.

SELECT IsEnabled FROM ActivityControl WHERE ActivityName = 'Activity1';


Check the value for IsEnabled is true or not if activity and place respective activity in true condition so if vale is 1 it will execute the activity.

@equals(activity('LookupActivity').output.firstRow.IsEnabled, 1)

Repeat this process for each activity to automatically enabled or disabled.

We are using Azure DevOps CICD for ADF deployment. In there we have an option to start and stop the triggers before and after the deployments.

what we need is to disable individual activity within pipeline , actual its all execute pipeline within a master pipeline.
